# AudioKit: Embedding AudioKit in Swift framework

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, audiokit

I am using Cocoapods 1.5.0, Xcode 9.3, Swift 4.1, and AudioKit 4.2.2.

I am creating an open source Swift framework for teaching coding in Swift. For generating sounds, I'd like my framework to both use AudioKit directly and also make AudioKit available as an import in apps built using my framework. Within my framework, I need to be able to access AudioKit:

```
import AudioKit
```

And within the main app, I want to be able to access features of my framework, and optionally access AudioKit directly like this:

```
import MySwiftFramework
import AudioKit
```

I have no problem adding AudioKit as a Cocoapods framework to the main app via my `Podfile`, but I am blocked trying to figure out how to add AudioKit to my framework. The expected way would be to declare it as a dependency in my own framework's `podspec` file:

```
spec.dependency 'AudioKit', '~> 4'
```

Having added this, `pod install` seems to run correctly, but attempting to `import AudioKit` in my framework's source files results in a `No such module 'AudioKit'` error at the import line.

Comment: I wonder if you might get more eyeballs on this if you don't explicitly state which framework you're using.  Sometimes people just assume they don't know audio stuff and move on.  I'm the opposite, I know some audio, but my framework embedding knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 3):

In my own frameworks, I create a podspec and a Podfile. In the podspec I specify the dependencies as you have shown. This tells the "client" of the framework that it needs that dependency in their own project.

In the framework's Podfile, I specify the dependencies that that framework relies on.

e.g.

```
pod 'AudioKit'
pod 'AudioKit/UI'
pod 'Audiobus'
```